# ExtJS - Filter buffered store with RegEx

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex, extjs

I've a MYSQL server connected to a buffered store. 
In some cases i must filter the records, the research must be case **Insensitive**, so I've used a regex to try checking the value in every case,because mysql server is case sensitive. Here is the code of research bar:

```
onSearchClick : function(){
        var me=this;
        if(me.getValue()!==''){
            var value=me.getValue();
            if(value.match(/ /g)){}else{
                value=value.split(""); //rome-> 'r''o''m''e'
                var valueApp='';
                Ext.Array.each(value, function(val) {
                    var m=val.toLowerCase();
                    var M=val.toUpperCase();
                    val='['+m+M+']';//also tryed with ()
                    valueApp=valueApp+val;
                });
                value=new RegExp(valueApp);
                console.log(value); //value=rome returns -> /[rR][oO][mM][eE]/
                me.store.filter{
                    property : me.paramName,
                    value    : value,
                    operator: '*=',
                    caseSensitive: false,
                    exactMatch: false,
                    anyMatch: true
                });
            }
            me.getTrigger('clear').show();
            me.updateLayout();
        }
    }
```

I can't match values, now all the values on the database are in uppercase, but probably they will change, so have you got a solution to this problem?
what is wrong in my code?

Using a filter with ROME as filter value the records are filtered successfully, but using regex no way to make it work.

```
EXAMPLEs:



 store.filter(param,value); //tryed with almost all options 
    search rome -> records with rome
    search Rome -> records with Rome

search ROME -> records with ROME
search /[rR][oO][mM][eE]/ -> no records
```

I need to have Always all the records

Comment: I just wonder if you can just pass `caseSensitive: false,` to the `me.store.filter`.

Comment: already tryed, but nothing, it just puts 'i' out of my string to compare it on mysql, but mysql can't read it.

Comment: Just FYI: if on the MySQL side the REGEXP is used without BINARY keyword, it performs a case insensitive search unless the settings are not default.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the server but I think the server is Binary. so no way to perform this way? The problem is on server query?

Comment: Some hints from the Web: 1) add `sortType: 'asUCString'`, 2) `re = new RegExp(value, "i"); store.filter(field, re);`, 3) `exactMatch: false,`, 4) `anyMatch: true`. And just FYI: a correct case-insensitive regex would be `/[rR][oO][mM][eE]/`. Without pipes.

Comment: i thought to use store loading datas on after render, but the amount of data are about 400 records in every table on mysql, so that's really slow. buffered store is my better solution to manage that amount of datas

Comment: edited question with your help but nothing happened :(

Comment: maybe mysql can't read the operator *= ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multitude of issues and misunderstandings here.

A minor note: even if the SQL server is binary, you should be able to set a character set and collation on a table.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html

But **the main thing is that you are mixing client-side filtering, server-side filtering, and a buffered store.**

Client-side filtering can only filter what's in the store at that time, so in a buffered store, you are not performing a search over all records. You would have to look into what ExtJS calls "remote filtering". This means that ExtJS sends the filter parameters to the server and **you have to implement the filter on the server side**. You are completely free to define a remote filter

```
property:'propertyThatTheStoreDoesntEvenKnowExists',
operator:'thisIsNotAnOperator',
value:'someValue'
```

and on the server side, **you then have to implement** a "filter function" that uses these variables (I use some pseudocode here):

```
filter = jsondecode(GET->filter);
if(filter->property=="propertyThatTheStoreDoesntEvenKnowExists" AND filter->operator=="thisIsNotAnOperator")
    result = mysql.buildQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE someProperty=@val").bind("@val",filter->value).execute();
else result = mysql.buildQuery("SELECT * FROM table").execute();
```

The store will then always contain all records that the server returns, no local filtering can be applied.

If you want to use client-side ("local") filtering, because you want to search the currently loaded set only, you can safely ignore all assumptions you have about MySQL features. What you have to care about is the strings that are returned to the client and can be found in the store. You are searching for perfect case-insensitive matches, so you can completely hand off regexp generation to ExtJS.

```
store.filter({
    property:'mySearchProperty',
    value:'rome',
    caseSensitive:false
})
```

should match Rome, rOme, ROME etc., but only searches the records that are in the store. So if you have a page size of 20, only the 20 records are searched and filtered down to those which contain that string. In this case you are bound to the predefined operators; or you can even define a custom function, which makes it possible to filter down about anything you want:

```
var value = textfield.getValue().toLowerCase();
store.filter({
    filterFn:function(record) {
        return record.get("myProperty").toLowerCase().indexOf(value)>-1;
    }
})
```

But you cannot use both remote and local filtering on the same store.

Comment: One moment, i've tryed to filter directly with ROME and the filter match correctly, the project isn't mine, but reading the code my filter is sent to server by the proxy with a select that returns the matching records. On server request the server "translate" the select on his sintax and execute it returning on my store only interested records

Comment: EXAMPLE: sending .filter(param,value) -> server execute:  select * from interestedTable where param (myoperator) value

Comment: my operator is converted by the server owner function, so *= (regex operator) is converted to REGEXP (mysql regex operator)

Comment: my select finally should be      select * from table where field REGEXP /[rR][oO][mM][eE]/

Comment: So we can't help you, because the most relevant parts of your code are not visible. "Should be", but then, it possibly isn't. If I were you, I'd have a look at changing the [column collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html).

Comment: So sorry about that xD 20 years old italian programmer starting working, not to much power to get all the code haha, I'll talk with the server owner to have other solutions

Comment: @Mr.George - `WHERE field REGEXP 'rome'` works as you want it to _if_ `field` is declared with a "case insensitive" collation.  There is no need for `[rR]` etc.

Comment: hey, solved a problem on the server, the server wasn't mine and there was a bug